# Как сделать так чтобы на кнопки мог нажимать только автор команды?

Tags: discord.py

Сделал кнопки в своём боте по написании команды. Всё работает хорошо, но на кнопки может нажимать каждый. Мне нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы на кнопки мог нажимать только тот, кто написал эту команду, а у других была **Ошибка взаимодействия.** Код:

```
async def button_one(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("Test #1")

@buttons.click
async def button_two(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("Test #2")

@buttons.click
async def button_three(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("Test #3")

@client.command()
async def create(ctx):
    await buttons.send(
        content = "Тестируем.", 
        channel = ctx.channel.id,
        components = [
            ActionRow([
                Button(
                    label="Да", 
                    style=ButtonType().Primary, 
                    custom_id="button_one"
                ),Button(
                    label="Возможно",
                    style=ButtonType().Secondary,
                    custom_id="button_two"
                )
            ]),ActionRow([
                Button(
                    label="Нет",
                    style=ButtonType().Danger,
                    custom_id="button_three"
                )
            ])
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать проверку:

```
def check(res):
    return ctx.author == res.user and res.channel == ctx.channel

res = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click", check=check, timeout=60)
await res.respond(type=InteractionType.ChannelMessageWithSource, embed=discord.Embed(description=(f"{res.component.label} pressed")))
```

None: `у меня используется библиотека discord-components`

Comment: SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что код выше надо занести в асинхронную функцию

Comment: Я сделал это, но остальные всё равно могут нажимать на кнопки.

Comment: Скорее всего это связано с тем что у меня не discord-components, а discord_buttons_plugin

Comment: Могу помочь через discord `RAINGM#1941`